# Suppressing command-line from Visual Studio (05/08) output

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to suppress the command-line from the output in Visual Studio - my plan is to add `/nologo` to the command-line - but I can't find a place in the application settings or in the IDE settings to do this.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but would really appreciate any enlightenment.

**Edit**: What is causing me the problem can best be described by the following scenario:

- I have a solution with multiple projects
- I hit F7, to build all (or all currently configured to build via the Configuration Manager)
- I hit F4 to step through the warnings/errors in the project(s)
- At the start of every project's output (which is usually 0 warnings and 0 errors) is a statement such as the following:

  *"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /reference:"c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ . . ."*

The fact that these are output for every project (esp. when those projects don't have warnings or errors) makes my stepping any bona-fide warnings/errors a right royal PITA. I want to have the IDE *not* display these pointless information lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Build and Run | MSBuild project build output verbosity -> Quiet

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't quite clear.  By default in VS2005, if you right-click a project, select properties, and look under Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General, I think you'll see Suppress Startup Banner: Yes (/nologo)
This suppresses some banner info from the compiler.  Is that what you want?